# Springdoc (OpenAPI 3) SpringBoot not generated correctly

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, springdoc

In a spring boot app with kotlin using the controller

```
//    @PostMapping("/:csv", consumes = [MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE]) // variant 1
    @PostMapping("/:csv")     // variant 2
    fun processKontoCsvFile(
        @RequestPart("revenues") @NotNull fileWithRevenues: MultipartFile,
        @RequestParam("bank") @NotNull bank: Bank
    ): ResponseEntity<String> {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(bank.name + " " + fileWithRevenues.name);
    }
```

the openapi is not generated correctly. Either the multipart file cannot be used as a selct (variant 2 above) or the enumeration value for variable bank (variant 1). See attached pictures.

[image]
[image]

Dependencies used, no extra configuration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-data-rest</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-kotlin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
```

What is needed to make that work?

**Update**:

It works with a `PathVariable` like so. But still don't know why not with a `RequestParam`

```
    @PostMapping("/{bank}/:csv", consumes = [MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE])
    fun processKontoCsvFile(
        @RequestPart("revenues") @NotNull fileWithRevenues: MultipartFile,
        @PathVariable("bank") @NotNull bank: Bank
    ): ResponseEntity<String> {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(bank.name + " " + fileWithRevenues.name);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using a Bank object instead of a string?

Comment: Because that is the api to the "outer" world in that case. A string could be anything. An enum defines a set of possible values. That should be a common use case.